# What does .str. stand for in .str.startswith()?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a silly question: I have used the following statement as one of arguments in Pandas boolean mask:

```
af['CTYNAME'].str.startswith('Washington')
```

I know what it does (looks for columns which start with 
'Washington'
 string. The problem is I am absolutely clueless about that .str.bit between defined column in af DataFrame, and the .startswith() method. Is it like a package I am importing that method from?

Apologies if this question is silly, but I basically snatched this bit of code from the other thread on StackOverflow, and I figured it worked but I didn`t know why.

Cheers,
Greem666

Comment: Yes it's a silly question, it means just string, synonymous with `.dt` methods where `dt` means `datetime`, you could've found this in the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#string-handling) easily, I suggest deleting this question as it has little value

Comment: use this ref http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html

Comment: Some knowledge of programming basics would be extraordinarily useful if you plan on using pandas.

Answer (score 0):

It means "string", int. means "integer" (1, 2, 3),